# Converting IFormFile to byte[] - Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, .net, iformfile

I am trying to **convert an IFormFile object to a byte[]** one, but I am bumping into the same error after several approaches:
**"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'."**

**DocumentController.Analyse() endpoint**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<AnalyseResponse>>> Analyse()
{
    logger.LogInformation($"GET /analyse called");

    //1. Getting cached documents
    var cachedFiles = this.documentService.GetUserDocuments(DEFAULT_USER);
    try
    {
        if (!cachedFiles.Any())
        {
            logger.LogError($"No documents cached for current user={DEFAULT_USER}");
            return StatusCode(400, $"No documents cached for current user={DEFAULT_USER}");
        }

        var fileBytes = new byte[cachedFiles[0].File.Length];
        if (cachedFiles[0].File.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await cachedFiles[0].File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
               // >> Code execution stops when executing CopyToAsync() <<
                fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
(......)
```

**DocumentService.GetUserDocuments(string userIdentifier)**

```
public List<DocumentDto> GetUserDocuments(string userIdentifier)
{
    this.memoryCache.TryGetValue(userIdentifier, out List<DocumentDto>? userDocs);
    return userDocs;
}
```

Broader context:

- This code is part of an API and gets executed when a GET endpoint is hit;
- I've read that HTTP context logging could influence on this, so I temporarily deactivated NLog just to make sure;

Comment: Please post the complete code of the `action method` or the `controller`

Comment: Side note: this is a highly inefficient method of handling streams. Ideally you would pass the whole stream to `GetIndicatorsValuesFromDocument` but at the least you could use the same byte array in the `MemoryStream` as the function call. Note that you are creating at least 3 arrays here, and the first is definitely unnecessary as you are overwriting it with another.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments - I have uploaded a bit more context now on the original question.

Comment: What is `DocumentDto`, how are you caching them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you storing `IFormFile` objects in your `DocumentService` and  trying to access them afterwards. `IFormFile` object lifetime is bound to request it originated from, so when request ends it got disposed. You should not cache them directly, instead you need to store it's content in some storage (of your choice: file, DB, RAM) and keep reference (i.e. file path) to it in `DocumentService`.

Comment: Most likely this is what is happening. The document is being cached (IFormFile) when another controller is executed previously called on the workflow, and when this one is executed, IFormFile has been disposed already given being a different request.
I will adapt the code so that a FileStream or a Byte[] is used for the contents of the file.
Will provide an update on this later.